# AJAX Toolkit Version

Tags: apex, javascript, developer, ajax-toolkit

Why is it so difficult to find the actual version numbers for the JavaScript and Apex toolkits?

For instance, how to I check whether

```
{!requireScript("/soap/ajax/37.0/connection.js")}
```

is the most recent version of the AJAX toolkit?

Comment: that number is actual salesforce API version. Point is that salesforce support older one so you dont need always use latest one. It may be dangerous sometimes

Comment: @kurunve Perfect. Upvoted and thank you for the answer.